# Auto-Updating Color Ramp of Raster to Current Display Extent using QGIS

Tags: qgis, display, color-ramp

When displaying raster files in QGIS with the color-ramp stretched to the min/max values of the current display extent, the min/max values don't update automatically when zooming or panning to a new area.

The only way I know around it is to manually recalculate the values each time.

How do I get the min/max extent to auto-update?

I'm currently using QGIS 2.4.0, but I encountered the same issue in all earlier versions I worked with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible on recent versions of QGIS (tested version 3.4.3-Madeira). To enable a colour ramp stretch that updates based on what data is onscreen:

1. Layer properties > Symbology
2. Expand "Min/Max Value Settings"
3. Under "Statistics extent", select "Updated canvas".

[image]

Your min and max colour ramp values will then dynamically update as you scroll around the map!

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you say is correct, but a plugin called "Raster" can help you a little bit. But this works only on grey scale.[image: Raster plugin]