# Dynamically styling LiDAR data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, style, lidar, dynamic

I am using QGIS 2.18.4 on Windows.
I have LiDAR data in GeoTiff format.

Is there a way to dynamically style the GeoTiff layer based on the current map extent?

I need to re-style the GeoTiff layer when I change the map extent in QGIS (pan or zoom). Basically I want the software to calculate the max and min values of the GeoTiff in the current map extent and apply a style (colour ramp) to those values, and when I change the map extent, the software needs to recalculate those max and min values.

I've been searching the internet and QGIS documentation but I haven't found any answers. I am not looking for web-based solutions.

Comment: Linking similar https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113311/auto-update-color-ramp-to-current-display-extent