# Color ramp that adjusts to changing scale in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, lidar, color-ramp

Is there a way in QGIS to have a color ramp for a raster layer (DEM layer), which adjusts to a changing scale while zooming in, and out, of the map extent?

Here is an online map made based on LIDAR, which does that: http://sggw.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=c0ecc5457a2249eba0fcfaeafd40f760

When you see the map as a whole, there seems to be little variation, but once you zoom in to a larger scale, the color ramp adjusts its colors to min and max values.

It would be great to create a map with an adjusting color ramp, that way I could show the whole picture, but also export maps showing local variations.

Comment: do you mean you want to have the ramp automatically adjust to the range of values in the extent? (As in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/113311/55203) ).

Comment: Pratically, the same question as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230524/dynamically-styling-lidar-data-in-qgis. Please, explain how it is different, and what you have tried.

Comment: Yes! But unfortunately it works only on grey scales. Is there a new tool working also on pseudocolor scales?