# Auto-updating color ramp of raster to current display extent using QGIS and rounding to whole numbers

Tags: raster, qgis-3, symbology, legend

I have an elevation dataset loaded into a QGIS 3.32 workspace. I want to update the symbology based on the currently displayed extent, but with "pretty" band values for use on a map/legend, i.e. each value range rounded to whole/half metres AOD. By using the method below, I can get the symbology to update automatically based on the canvas extent, but the values associated with each colour band are seemingly random decimals based on the canvas statistics. (e.g. 60.6439918... 61.6839684...) The solution can use python if necessary.

1. Layer properties > Symbology
2. Expand "Min/Max Value Settings"
3. Under "Statistics extent", select "Updated canvas".

Comment: Method used so far:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113311/auto-updating-color-ramp-of-raster-to-current-display-extent-using-qgis